# What's the Halacha on Kohanim that lie to marry converts or divorcees?

Tags: halacha, marriage, kohen-priest, sheker-false

What's the Halacha on Kohanim that lie to marry converts or divorcees?

Are they permanently unable to regain their status if they divorced the forbidden relationship or are they able to regain status just like any other typical Kohanim-forbidden relationship?

The key being that in this situation, the Kohen lies about being a Kohen to get into a forbidden marriage. A local Rav orally stated that the Kohen would permanently be banned of his Kohen status in this unique scenario, but what is Halacha for this?

Comment: Is there any Halaka on this at all?